# How can I use the cvendthru parameter in Clickbank IPN notification?

Tags: api, paypal-ipn, clickbank

I'm trying to integrate Clickbank as a payment platform for a client, and basically I want to send a parameter that I can later get back in the IPN I receive from them, to be able to match the IPN notification to the originating payment

To initiate the payment, I basically redirect to:

```
http://productid.vendor.pay.clickbank.net
```

That's all, no parameters at all.

However, I do see, in the [documentation for IPN](http://www.clickbank.com/help/affiliate-help/affiliate-tools/instant-notification-service/) there is a parameter "cvendthru" that seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Problem is, there is no other mention as to how to use this, how to actually pass information that'll come back in that parameter, and google searches aren't turning up anything very helpful.

Has anyone used this before?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I just tried the first thing that came to mind after not finding anything in Google, and it worked...

As simple as this:

```
http://productid.vendor.pay.clickbank.net/?var1=aaa&var2=bbb
```

Perfect

Comment: Just to confirm - after buying through this url the `cvendthru` parameter contains `var1=aaa&var2=bbb`?